# replace single quotes in string with \'

Tags: c++, string, stl

I have a string that contains ' characters. I want to replace all of them with \' as this is used for inserting into the database. Can some one suggest me an efficient way to do this? Unfortunately, I cannot use boost and limited to STL.

Comment: Tip: don't sanitize your input like that, just use parametric queries and forget about this kind of problems. What DB library are you using?

Comment: Its DB2. Unfortunately there is a large legacy and I cannot make that significant change currently. But I would still love to know the parametric query method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't forget to also escape `\` when it occurs in the source string.

```
std::string escape(std::string const &s)
{
    std::size_t n = s.length();
    std::string escaped;
    escaped.reserve(n * 2);        // pessimistic preallocation

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (s[i] == '\\' || s[i] == '\'')
            escaped += '\\';
        escaped += s[i];
    }
    return escaped;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is best to do the copy into a new string as this is far more efficient, because otherwise each time you insert a character, it will shift the bytes which is very inefficient. In addition you may well find it hard keeping your iterators valid.

The simplest way is to write a loop to create the new one, although you could use a functor that does the insert into the new string on each iteration.

```
struct escaper
{
  std::string& target;
  explicit escaper( std::string& t ) : target( t ) {}

  void operator()( char ch ) const
  {
     if( ch == '\'') // or switch on any character that 
                     // needs escaping like \ itself
     {
        target.push_back('\\');
     }
     target.push_back( ch );
  }
};

std::string escaped;
std::for_each( instr.begin(), instr.end(), escaper(escaped));
```